# Can't achieve smooth scrolling vie scroll-behavior css property in Chrome (but can in Firefox)

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox

I have 2 html elements. When I click the first element I want to scroll to the second element, and since I want the scrolling to be smooth I don't want to use jQuery or any js for this particular matter I use the `scroll-behavior` css property:

```
<style>
  body {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <a id="firstElement" href="#secondElement">
  <!-- some other divs -->
  <div id="secondElement"
</body>
```

When I click on the fist element it gets me to the second, however the smooth scrolling only happens in Firefox and from what I know it should also happen in Google Chrome. When I inspect the `body` element I see a warning message stating

> Unknown property name

for "scroll-behavior".

Comment: It's not supported in Chrome. http://caniuse.com/#search=scroll

Comment: Thanks, I also found it in here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior 'Supported in Chrome by enabling the "Smooth Scrolling" or "Enable experimental web platform features" flag in chrome://flags.'

Comment: That won't work for your users though O.o

Comment: Yeah, for now I'll have to settle using javascript

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49636727/why-is-scroll-behaviorsmooth-not-working-but-javascript-window-scroll-smooth-is/58778396#58778396