# Why is scroll-behavior:smooth not working but javascript window.scroll smooth is?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a navigation bar to scroll down to anchor elements. The navbar is inside the body.

My css :

```
body {
        scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

In the page, I also use some javascript. One is a javascript with the following function to navigate to other page elements  :

```
window.scroll({
    top : pos,
    left : 0,
    behavior : 'smooth'
});
```

With Chrome, when I call the javascript function, the scroll is smooth. But when I navigate to anchors through navigation bar links, it is not smooth.

Would someone care to explain me why ?

Also with Firefox both scroll from navigation bar & javascript function are smooth. I think it's a bit wierd that one work but not the other.

EDIT : my workaround is as follow (vanilla JS / works with all modern browsers) :

```
    let pos = document.querySelector(element).offsetTop;
    if ('scrollBehavior' in document.documentElement.style) { //Checks if browser supports scroll function
        window.scroll({
            top : pos,
            left : 0,
            behavior : 'smooth'
        });
    } else {
        smoothScrollTo(0, pos, 500); //polyfill below
    }
```

And the fallback scroll function :

```
window.smoothScrollTo = function(endX, endY, duration) {
        let startX = window.scrollX || window.pageXOffset,
        startY = window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset,
        distanceX = endX - startX,
        distanceY = endY - startY,
        startTime = new Date().getTime();

        // Easing function
        let easeInOutQuart = function(time, from, distance, duration) {
            if ((time /= duration / 2) < 1) return distance / 2 * time * time * time * time + from;
            return -distance / 2 * ((time -= 2) * time * time * time - 2) + from;
        };

        let timer = window.setInterval(function() {
            let time = new Date().getTime() - startTime,
            newX = easeInOutQuart(time, startX, distanceX, duration),
            newY = easeInOutQuart(time, startY, distanceY, duration);
            if (time >= duration) {
                window.clearInterval(timer);
            }
            window.scrollTo(newX, newY);
        }, 1000 / 60); // 60 fps
    };
```

Comment: It works for me if I set the scroll-behavior style on the html element (scroll viewport can depend on your overflow styles on html and body element). If you still want to use JS to do it you should not forget to set the focus after the scroll to not break keyboard accessibility.

Comment: Yes I think it has been fixed in the recent updates.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on [documentation](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view/#smooth-scrolling), `scroll-behavior: smooth` not working on `body` element ([try it](https://jsfiddle.net/k6qt5xno/20/)):

> The scroll-behavior property of the HTML body element is not
>   propagated to the viewport.

But it works on other selectors like `html` ([try here](https://jsfiddle.net/k6qt5xno/19/)).

Also you can try pure JavaScript solution ([example](https://jsfiddle.net/k6qt5xno/21/)):

```
function scrollToTop() {
  window.scrollTo({
    top: 1000,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
}
```

Comment: `scroll-behavior: smooth` doesn't work in Chrome _(e.g. in version 88.0.4324.182)_ without **enabling chrome://flags/#smooth-scrolling**

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me:

```
* {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's been some time, but some people have their JavaScript disabled on browsers, so I don't think that would be the best option. The problem with adding: `body {scroll-behavior: smooth;}` is that it won't work unless you add it to the `html`. For example:

On `body`:

```css
body {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

a {
  background-color: lightgray;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: black;
  right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>No Scroll Effect On Body</title>
</head>
<body>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas gravida varius turpis, ac dignissim purus molestie quis. Aliquam erat volutpat. Aenean ipsum neque, faucibus ut imperdiet nec, aliquam eget purus. Phasellus ultricies porttitor neque, a porttitor tortor pulvinar non. Phasellus in orci porttitor nulla mattis cursus nec ut ex. Vivamus non elit at dolor imperdiet bibendum. Ut leo dolor, aliquet ut magna eu, hendrerit consequat quam. Pellentesque eget odio felis. Integer id posuere mi. Ut quis velit pulvinar, auctor sem nec, consectetur diam. Fusce sed ex eu sem bibendum aliquam ultrices ut ipsum. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aenean imperdiet ex eu velit malesuada volutpat. Sed molestie imperdiet condimentum. In suscipit, nulla nec viverra tristique, dui tellus tristique mi, eget laoreet tortor nunc vel nunc. Nam tristique rutrum vulputate.

Donec imperdiet nisl non ligula ultricies condimentum. Suspendisse nisi est, lobortis vitae enim at, porta mollis erat. Sed in orci nunc. Aliquam non dui et urna volutpat dignissim varius sed nulla. Duis fringilla vestibulum ipsum, a fringilla sapien bibendum vel. Pellentesque non viverra magna, sed laoreet orci. Donec elit eros, imperdiet sit amet risus sed, placerat fermentum sem. In porta felis vulputate, suscipit nisi maximus, fringilla tellus. Vivamus nec dui accumsan, suscipit eros nec, sodales sapien. Mauris et viverra lectus. Curabitur massa quam, lacinia aliquam ante eget, auctor sollicitudin turpis. Phasellus imperdiet eros ornare arcu pulvinar, id cursus arcu volutpat. Nam sit amet magna eu magna suscipit posuere id quis nisi.

Quisque a diam sed magna luctus dignissim sit amet et elit. Vivamus fringilla posuere sapien eu posuere. Proin bibendum libero ac eros maximus vehicula. Sed et diam eu lorem gravida pharetra at sed mauris. Cras dictum urna fringilla quam luctus elementum. Maecenas tincidunt arcu dolor, eget venenatis ex ornare eu. Vestibulum tempor tempus finibus. Mauris posuere, enim eu ornare molestie, quam urna iaculis massa, eu lacinia eros odio ac quam. Sed sem nunc, sollicitudin in imperdiet eu, molestie vel libero. Morbi in dui ut enim pharetra dictum egestas tempus velit. Morbi accumsan justo nec faucibus pulvinar. Ut pellentesque auctor purus. Maecenas id sagittis enim, tempor tristique quam.

Proin condimentum posuere scelerisque. Maecenas egestas vehicula vestibulum. Vestibulum pharetra nunc nec orci scelerisque, fermentum pellentesque quam pretium. Nam odio tortor, aliquet nec sem quis, rutrum ornare lectus. Fusce scelerisque ullamcorper lacus vitae hendrerit. Donec tincidunt quis dolor ut sollicitudin. Vestibulum feugiat diam at odio fringilla, id ullamcorper diam scelerisque. Aenean tempor tincidunt turpis id porttitor. Mauris gravida eleifend lorem, pellentesque cursus odio volutpat et. Mauris est nunc, bibendum congue purus vitae, luctus elementum est. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.

<br />
<br />
<br />

<a href="#top">Go to top</a>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, it is not possible to work if it set on the `body`. But it will work if it set on the `html`:

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

a {
  background-color: lightgray;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: black;
  right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <title>No Scroll Effect On Body</title>
</head>

<body>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas gravida varius turpis, ac dignissim purus molestie quis. Aliquam erat volutpat. Aenean ipsum neque, faucibus ut imperdiet nec, aliquam eget purus. Phasellus ultricies porttitor neque, a
  porttitor tortor pulvinar non. Phasellus in orci porttitor nulla mattis cursus nec ut ex. Vivamus non elit at dolor imperdiet bibendum. Ut leo dolor, aliquet ut magna eu, hendrerit consequat quam. Pellentesque eget odio felis. Integer id posuere mi.
  Ut quis velit pulvinar, auctor sem nec, consectetur diam. Fusce sed ex eu sem bibendum aliquam ultrices ut ipsum. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aenean imperdiet ex eu velit malesuada volutpat. Sed molestie imperdiet condimentum. In suscipit, nulla
  nec viverra tristique, dui tellus tristique mi, eget laoreet tortor nunc vel nunc. Nam tristique rutrum vulputate. Donec imperdiet nisl non ligula ultricies condimentum. Suspendisse nisi est, lobortis vitae enim at, porta mollis erat. Sed in orci nunc.
  Aliquam non dui et urna volutpat dignissim varius sed nulla. Duis fringilla vestibulum ipsum, a fringilla sapien bibendum vel. Pellentesque non viverra magna, sed laoreet orci. Donec elit eros, imperdiet sit amet risus sed, placerat fermentum sem. In
  porta felis vulputate, suscipit nisi maximus, fringilla tellus. Vivamus nec dui accumsan, suscipit eros nec, sodales sapien. Mauris et viverra lectus. Curabitur massa quam, lacinia aliquam ante eget, auctor sollicitudin turpis. Phasellus imperdiet eros
  ornare arcu pulvinar, id cursus arcu volutpat. Nam sit amet magna eu magna suscipit posuere id quis nisi. Quisque a diam sed magna luctus dignissim sit amet et elit. Vivamus fringilla posuere sapien eu posuere. Proin bibendum libero ac eros maximus
  vehicula. Sed et diam eu lorem gravida pharetra at sed mauris. Cras dictum urna fringilla quam luctus elementum. Maecenas tincidunt arcu dolor, eget venenatis ex ornare eu. Vestibulum tempor tempus finibus. Mauris posuere, enim eu ornare molestie, quam
  urna iaculis massa, eu lacinia eros odio ac quam. Sed sem nunc, sollicitudin in imperdiet eu, molestie vel libero. Morbi in dui ut enim pharetra dictum egestas tempus velit. Morbi accumsan justo nec faucibus pulvinar. Ut pellentesque auctor purus. Maecenas
  id sagittis enim, tempor tristique quam. Proin condimentum posuere scelerisque. Maecenas egestas vehicula vestibulum. Vestibulum pharetra nunc nec orci scelerisque, fermentum pellentesque quam pretium. Nam odio tortor, aliquet nec sem quis, rutrum ornare
  lectus. Fusce scelerisque ullamcorper lacus vitae hendrerit. Donec tincidunt quis dolor ut sollicitudin. Vestibulum feugiat diam at odio fringilla, id ullamcorper diam scelerisque. Aenean tempor tincidunt turpis id porttitor. Mauris gravida eleifend
  lorem, pellentesque cursus odio volutpat et. Mauris est nunc, bibendum congue purus vitae, luctus elementum est. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
  elit. Maecenas gravida varius turpis, ac dignissim purus molestie quis. Aliquam erat volutpat. Aenean ipsum neque, faucibus ut imperdiet nec, aliquam eget purus. Phasellus ultricies porttitor neque, a porttitor tortor pulvinar non. Phasellus in orci
  porttitor nulla mattis cursus nec ut ex. Vivamus non elit at dolor imperdiet bibendum. Ut leo dolor, aliquet ut magna eu, hendrerit consequat quam. Pellentesque eget odio felis. Integer id posuere mi. Ut quis velit pulvinar, auctor sem nec, consectetur
  diam. Fusce sed ex eu sem bibendum aliquam ultrices ut ipsum. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aenean imperdiet ex eu velit malesuada volutpat. Sed molestie imperdiet condimentum. In suscipit, nulla nec viverra tristique, dui tellus tristique mi, eget
  laoreet tortor nunc vel nunc. Nam tristique rutrum vulputate. Donec imperdiet nisl non ligula ultricies condimentum. Suspendisse nisi est, lobortis vitae enim at, porta mollis erat. Sed in orci nunc. Aliquam non dui et urna volutpat dignissim varius
  sed nulla. Duis fringilla vestibulum ipsum, a fringilla sapien bibendum vel. Pellentesque non viverra magna, sed laoreet orci. Donec elit eros, imperdiet sit amet risus sed, placerat fermentum sem. In porta felis vulputate, suscipit nisi maximus, fringilla
  tellus. Vivamus nec dui accumsan, suscipit eros nec, sodales sapien. Mauris et viverra lectus. Curabitur massa quam, lacinia aliquam ante eget, auctor sollicitudin turpis. Phasellus imperdiet eros ornare arcu pulvinar, id cursus arcu volutpat. Nam sit
  amet magna eu magna suscipit posuere id quis nisi. Quisque a diam sed magna luctus dignissim sit amet et elit. Vivamus fringilla posuere sapien eu posuere. Proin bibendum libero ac eros maximus vehicula. Sed et diam eu lorem gravida pharetra at sed
  mauris. Cras dictum urna fringilla quam luctus elementum. Maecenas tincidunt arcu dolor, eget venenatis ex ornare eu. Vestibulum tempor tempus finibus. Mauris posuere, enim eu ornare molestie, quam urna iaculis massa, eu lacinia eros odio ac quam. Sed
  sem nunc, sollicitudin in imperdiet eu, molestie vel libero. Morbi in dui ut enim pharetra dictum egestas tempus velit. Morbi accumsan justo nec faucibus pulvinar. Ut pellentesque auctor purus. Maecenas id sagittis enim, tempor tristique quam. Proin
  condimentum posuere scelerisque. Maecenas egestas vehicula vestibulum. Vestibulum pharetra nunc nec orci scelerisque, fermentum pellentesque quam pretium. Nam odio tortor, aliquet nec sem quis, rutrum ornare lectus. Fusce scelerisque ullamcorper lacus
  vitae hendrerit. Donec tincidunt quis dolor ut sollicitudin. Vestibulum feugiat diam at odio fringilla, id ullamcorper diam scelerisque. Aenean tempor tincidunt turpis id porttitor. Mauris gravida eleifend lorem, pellentesque cursus odio volutpat et.
  Mauris est nunc, bibendum congue purus vitae, luctus elementum est. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <a href="#top">Go to top</a> </body>

</html>
```

The good thing about this is that it is a cross-browser solution, as it is very uncommon to find a browser that disabled CSS. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to try to smooth scroll using jQuery. I think native scrolling might not always support the smooth scroll. You'd be much safer using jQuery.

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
```

If you are using other anchors, you need to make sure they prevent default jumping and scroll. I'd use jQuery also.

Ref: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. I'm trying to stay away from Jquery atm. I have a vanilla Javascript function for smooth scroll if needed. I was wondering why the "css" smooth behavior wasn't working while the javascript that calls a window scroll with smooth behavior is.

Comment: I can't tell why it doesn't work in CSS. Not so sure, but you should use a polyfill if you consider using vanilla Javascript to make sure it works everywhere. Please look at this: http://iamdustan.com/smoothscroll/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you still need an answer to this, but I came across an article that fixed it for me with just css: https://www.fourkitchens.com/blog/article/fix-scrolling-performance-css-will-change-property/

Answer (score -2):

```
enter code here
```

```js
setInterval(myTimer, 1);     
var isTimerEnable = false;
var scroll_position = 0;
var getSelected_position =0;
var getCurrent_position =0;
var scroll_speed = 5;

function Current_Position(){
    getCurrent_position = window.pageYOffset;
}
function myTimer() {
    if(isTimerEnable == true){
        if(scroll_position < getSelected_position){
            scroll_position +=scroll_speed;
            getCurrent_position =scroll_position;
            window.scroll(0,scroll_position);
            if(scroll_position >= getSelected_position){
                isTimerEnable = false;
            } 
        }
        else{
            scroll_position -=scroll_speed;
            getCurrent_position =scroll_position;
            window.scroll(0,scroll_position);
            if(scroll_position <= getSelected_position){
                isTimerEnable = false;
            } 
        }
    }
   
}
//NOTE ASSIGN THE Y POSITION OF YOUR DIV 
function topNav_btn(setPosition){
    scroll_position = getCurrent_position;
    getSelected_position = setPosition;  
    isTimerEnable  =true;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <title>No Scroll Effect On Body</title>
</head>

<body>

  <button style="position:fixed; left:200px;" onclick="topNav_btn(0);">Go to form 1 </button>
  <button style="position:fixed; left:300px;" onclick="topNav_btn(450);">Go to form 2 </button>
  <button style="position:fixed; left:400px;" onclick="topNav_btn(900);">Go to form 3 </button>
   <div id="form1">  Form 1   </div>
   <br> <br> <br><br> <br> <br><br><br>  <br> <br> <br><br> <br> <br><br><br> 
   <br> <br> <br><br> <br> <br><br><br> 
  
  <div id="form2">  Form 2 </div> 
  
 <br> <br> <br><br> <br> <br><br><br>  <br> <br> <br><br> <br> <br><br><br> 
   <br> <br> <br><br> <br> <br><br><br> 
   
     <div id="form2">  Form 3 </div> 
  
 <br> <br> <br><br> <br> <br><br><br>  <br> <br> <br><br> <br> <br><br><br> 
   <br> <br> <br><br> <br> <br><br><br> 
 
    
    
   
    
      
     
 
     
     
 
  

     
 
  
  
  
  </body>

</html>
```